# Hibernate generates too long identifiers for Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate

We are using JPA with Hibernate 4.3.8 and Oracle 11. Our entities doesn't have explicit DB identifier names declared in annotations and so we rely upon Hibernate to generate them correctly.

For MySQL it works properly but after we had switched to Oracle then we've encountered couple of the problems.

One of them is that Hibernate-generated schema contains identifiers longer than Oracle supports. We thought that `Oracle10gDialect` handles it but it seems we were wrong.

What is the best approach to add support of Oracle to our application? Must we explicitly declare all the database tables/columns/indexes... in annotations (`@Table`, `@Column`...)? Shouldn't it be Hibernate who takes a care of this dialect-specific task?

Another problem is that Hibernate also doesn't escape the keywords (eg. column name `code` must be escaped in Oracle). What if we decide to support another database in the future? Must we choose all the identifier names so that all of them suit for every DB? This seems to be very overhelming. (Note that the property `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` can solve it partially but then `@UniqueConstraint` columns doesn't match.)

Or maybe... does Eclipselink handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such cases you can use Hibernate's **NamingStrategy** prepared for Oracle.
In simple words: `NamingStrategy` tells Hibernate how to *generate names for columns or tables*.

You can provide **oracle-aware** `NamingStrategy` as I do for each of my Oracle/Hibernate projects.

Here is sample JPA configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
  ...

<property name="jpaPropertyMap">
 <map>
  <entry key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="com.mycompany.OracleNamingStrategy"/>
  <entry key="hibernate.dialect"         value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    ...
 </map>
</property>
</bean>
```

Here is the NamingStrategy I have been using for many projects:

https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-naming-strategy-for-oracle/source/browse/trunk/src/de/schauderhaft/hibernate/OracleNamingStrategy.java

look at smart abbreviating method that guarantees to produce Oracle-compliant name:

```
public static String abbreviateName(String someName) {
    if (someName.length() <= MAX_LENGTH)
        return someName;

    String[] tokens = splitName(someName);
    shortenName(someName, tokens);

    return assembleResults(tokens);
}
```

There are many articles about applying `NamingStratety` with Hibernate, for example:

1.
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/

2.
http://sudhirmongia.blogspot.com/2010/08/naming-strategy-in-hibernate.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your solution in the following days and will accept your answer if no blocker arises. Still, I wonder why it is not built directly into Hibernate (eg. to `Oracle10gDialect`).

Comment: Nice to see, that this thingy is still useful.

Comment: Since the OracleNamingStrategie moved to GitHub I thought it would be good to have the link here:
https://github.com/schauder/hibernate-naming-strategy-for-oracle